# How can I align and resize these two elements with Storyboard Auto Layout?

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, uistoryboard, xcode-storyboard

I am designing a very simple "Today" widget with just two elements: a text label (shown here with a red background) and an info button. I want the info button to always appear right after the label.

So:

1. the info button should always stick to the right margin
2. the label should always stick to the left margin
3. the label should resize itself so it is the full width of the available space, right up to the edge of the button

How can I do this?! Auto Layout is sooooo confusing and I've been playing with it for an hour with no luck. Can't figure out where to start. I think I need at least three constraints, one for each of the needs above...

[image]

Comment: give label `top, left, right , bottom` constraint and for button `right, top, bottom and width`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `info` button will have a fixed width and height. Set its right margin to the parent right. Set your red label's left margin to parent left and right margin to info button's left.

Now since your red label doesn't have a width restriction, it will take all of the width between left margin and right margin.

This is how it looks. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: This all sounds absolutely correct to me-- I understand what you're suggesting-- but I'm not sure how to add these constraints. For example, exactly where/how in the interface can I set the info button's right margin to the parent right margin (pinning it to the right edge)? Sorry, I'm just stuck and all the online references I've found are super confusing. :-(

Comment: @Eric.. Once you have aligned your buttons and set their sizes, select your infoButton and then at the bottom of the editor, select the second button from the right (it's the one that has a triangle button on it right). This would show you add new constraints pop up. Set the width and height and set the constraint. Select the dotted T shaped lines and set their values (for info button you would need to select the top and right T shaped red line and set its values to zero.

Comment: @ShamasS thank you, still struggling, lol. I did exactly as you suggested and it's getting closer - see http://imgur.com/AoRPuyv and the result -> http://imgur.com/AhbO5GK .... Now the info button is staying glued to the right, but now the text field is a fixed width. I tried to remove its width constraint and pin it to the top left of the parent (top and left "T" red lines, values to 0) but then it starts complaining about duplicate rules. Arggggh so unclear.

Comment: Also, my info button is falling off the edge, which is weird: if the margin is 0, shouldn't it be right on the edge (not clipped)? And, when I try to bring it in by setting the constraint to 8 or -8 (not sure which was right so I tried both), it creates other error messages. And as I change the message in my label field, it changes the width of the field so the info button is pushed off the screen. This thing is too complicated for its own good. I understand the concept of relative spacing and why it's the "right" way to do this but the tool is so counter-intuitive.

Comment: UPDATE thank you @ShamasS for everything... I am making progress! Deleted all the constraints and then started over with unchecking "Constrain to margins" which appears to be working much better. Slowly I'm getting there...

Comment: @Eric cool. glad to be of help. Mark the answer as accepted if this helped.

Comment: @ShamasS my pleasure. Thanks again. Pretty much have it working well :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should create top, bottom, width and trailing (to the container view) constraint info button. 
For the label, they should be leading, top, bottom (to the container view) and horizontal spacing to the info button. 
Hope that will help.